# Highcharts series (column) names of x axis

Tags: highcharts

I have a script that returns a chart (Highcharts) and it works fine apart from not displaying the names of the columns on the x axis. Can anyone see where I have gone wrong.

My Json:
    [{"data":[30.95]},{"data":[2.38]},{"data":[66.67]}]

My script:

```
$(function () {

var colors = ['#FF0000','#FF9900','#009900'];
colorIterator = 0;
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {

$.getJSON("../charts/1-2-4-reports_chart.php?TAG=<?php echo $_POST['SectionVar'];?>&From=<?php echo $StartDate;?>&To=<?php echo $EndDate;?>", function(json) {

chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
renderTo: 'container1',
type: 'column',
height: 200,
marginRight: 25,
marginBottom: 25,
plotBackgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
style: {
fontFamily: 'serif',
fontSize: '8px',
}
},

title: {
text: 'Net Promoter Score: <?php echo $_POST['SectionVar'];?>',
x: -20,
style: {
fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
color: '#000000',
fontWeight: 'normal',
fontSize: '11px'
} //center
},

subtitle: {
text: '',
},

xAxis: {
categories: ['Detractors', 'Passives', 'Promoters'],
title: {
text: ''

}
},

yAxis: {

//reversedStacks: false,
endOnTick: false,
max:101,
showFirstLabel: false,
lineColor:'#999',
lineWidth:1,
tickColor:'#666',
tickWidth:1,
tickLength:2,
tickInterval: 10,
gridLineColor:'#ddd',
title: {
text: '',
style: {
fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
color: '#000000',
fontWeight: 'bold',
fontSize: '8px'
}
},
plotLines: [{
color: '#808080'
}]
},

credits: {
enabled: false
},

tooltip: {
formatter: function() {
return '<b>Guest responses: '+ this.y +'<br/>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>Month:'+
this.x;
}
},



navigation: {
buttonOptions: {
verticalAlign: 'top',
y: -10,
x: -20
}
},

legend: {
enabled: false,
layout: 'vertical',
align: 'right',
verticalAlign: 'top',
x: -10,
y: 100,
borderWidth: 1
},

colors: [
'#FF0000',
'#FF9900',
'#009900',
],

plotOptions: {
column: {
colorByPoint: false
},

series: {
type: 'column',
cursor: 'pointer',
pointWidth: 30,
point: {
events: {
//click: function() {
//location.href = "feedback-items_detractors_iframe.php?FromDate1=<?php echo $StartDate;?>&ToDate1=<?php echo $EndDate;?> target='iframe2'";
//}
}
},

legendIndex:0,

dataLabels: {
enabled: true,
color: '#000000',
align: 'center',
cursor: 'pointer',
//borderRadius: 5,
//backgroundColor: 'rgba(252, 255, 255, 255)',
//borderWidth: 1,
//borderColor: '#AAA',
y: -6,
format: '{y:.2f} %', // one decimal
y: -20, // 10 pixels down from the top
this.series.name
style: {
textShadow: false,
fontSize: '8px',
fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
}
}
}

},

exporting: {
chartOptions: { // specific options for the exported image
plotOptions: {
series: {
dataLabels: {
enabled: true
}
}
}
},
fallbackToExportServer: false
},



series: json,

});
});

});


});
```

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made some syntax errors in your code, fixed version below:

```
$(function() {

  var colors = ['#FF0000', '#FF9900', '#009900'];
  var colorIterator = 0;
  var chart;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    const json = [{"data":[30.95]},{"data":[2.38]},{"data":[66.67]}]
    setTimeout(function() {
      chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'container1',
          type: 'column',
          height: 200,
          marginRight: 25,
          marginBottom: 25,
          plotBackgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
          style: {
            fontFamily: 'serif',
            fontSize: '8px',
          }
        },

        title: {
          text: '',
          x: -20,
          style: {
            fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
            color: '#000000',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            fontSize: '11px'
          } //center
        },

        subtitle: {
          text: '',
        },

        xAxis: {
          categories: ['Detractors', 'Passives', 'Promoters'],
          title: {
            text: ''

          }
        },

        yAxis: {

          //reversedStacks: false,
          endOnTick: false,
          max: 101,
          showFirstLabel: false,
          lineColor: '#999',
          lineWidth: 1,
          tickColor: '#666',
          tickWidth: 1,
          tickLength: 2,
          tickInterval: 10,
          gridLineColor: '#ddd',
          title: {
            text: '',
            style: {
              fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
              color: '#000000',
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              fontSize: '8px'
            }
          },
          plotLines: [{
            color: '#808080'
          }]
        },

        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },

        tooltip: {
          formatter: function() {
            return '<b>Guest responses: ' + this.y + '<br/>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>Month:' +
              this.x;
          }
        },



        navigation: {
          buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: -10,
            x: -20
          }
        },

        legend: {
          enabled: false,
          layout: 'vertical',
          align: 'right',
          verticalAlign: 'top',
          x: -10,
          y: 100,
          borderWidth: 1
        },

        colors: [
          '#FF0000',
          '#FF9900',
          '#009900',
        ],

        plotOptions: {
          column: {
            colorByPoint: false
          }
        },

        series: {
          type: 'column',
          cursor: 'pointer',
          pointWidth: 30,
          point: {
            events: {
            }
          },

          legendIndex: 0,

          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000',
            align: 'center',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            y: -6,
            format: '{y:.2f} %', // one decimal
            y: -20, // 10 pixels down from the top
            style: {
              textShadow: false,
              fontSize: '8px',
              fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
          }
        },

        exporting: {
          chartOptions: { // specific options for the exported image
            plotOptions: {
              series: {
                dataLabels: {
                  enabled: true
                }
              }
            }
          },
          fallbackToExportServer: false
        },
        series: json,
      });
    });
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0kjojak9/

Comment: Hi and thanks for your support. I have run your fiddle but the column names do not appear on the x axis, just the word "Detractors". Many thanks again,

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jh3znk21/, `[{ data: [30.95, 2.38, 66.67] }]` categories are assigned to each data value. You defined 3 series with one point each, so you got 1 category for one point of each series. Don't forget to accept the response if it was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: again many thanks for your time. Your fiddle works great but I have lost the individual column colours as Detractors (red), Passives (orange) and Promoters (green. Is there a way get those colours back?

Comment: @stpos hi. looking at your fiddle I think my issue may be with the json data. My data looks like:[{"data":[20.37]},{"data":[37.04]},{"data":[42.59]}]. I can't see how I can incorrporate the colour of each column. Or am I looking at this completely wrong.

Comment: hi again. Thanks for all your help and time, i now have all the issues resolved.